# Problem inheriting from a Toplevel window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I designed in tkinter/Python a modal window (CModalForm) inheriting from Toplevel. It permits to use a background color or a background image that resizes together with the window. CModalForm should be a base to create more complex windows inheriting from it. For instance, for testing it, I want to create a login window inheriting from CModalForm and having an image as background and a couple of Text and Entry widgets. To see the background I set 'SystemButtonFace' as transparent color so that widgets added to the login form does not overlap to the background image but the effect is that the login form expands by itself indefinitely. Below my code:

```
from tkinter import Toplevel, BOTH, YES
from tkinter.ttk import Label
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class CModalForm(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, winParent, formTitle, centeredOnParent=False, centeredOnScreen=False, modal=True, bkgColor=None, bkgImg=None, **kwargs):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.withdraw()
        self.parent = winParent
        self.title( formTitle )      
        self.transient(winParent)
        self.grab_set()
        
        if bkgImg != None:
            self.image = Image.open("../idata/" + bkgImg)
            self.img_copy= self.image.copy()
            self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
            self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
            # self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            self.background.grid(sticky="nswe")
            self.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image) # Bind the toplevel, not the label
        else:
            if bkgColor != None:
                pass
        if centeredOnScreen == True:
            self.centerOnScreen()
        elif centeredOnParent == True:
            self.centerOnParent()
        self.deiconify()
        if modal == True:
            winParent.wait_window(self)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def _resize_image(self,event):
        # These are now the height/width of the window
        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height
        # Check if the image is the same size as the window
        if self.background.winfo_width() != new_width or self.background.winfo_height() != new_height:
            # If it isn't, resize
            self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))
            self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
            self.background.configure(image = self.background_image)        
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    '''
    # Apparently a common hack to get the window size. Temporarily hide the
    # window to avoid update_idletasks() drawing the window in the wrong
    # position.
    root.withdraw()
    root.update_idletasks()  # Update "requested size" from geometry manager
    
    x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
    y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
    root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
    
    # This seems to draw the window frame immediately, so only call deiconify()
    # after setting correct window position
    root.deiconify()    
    '''
    def centerOnParent(self):
        # self.parent.withdraw()
        # self.parent.update_idletasks()  # Update "requested size" from geometry manager
        
        master_pos_x = self.master.winfo_x()
        master_pos_y = self.master.winfo_y()
        master_width = self.master.winfo_width()
        master_height = self.master.winfo_height()
        my_width = self.winfo_reqwidth()
        my_height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        pos_x = (master_pos_x + (master_width // 2)) - (my_width // 2)
        pos_y = (master_pos_y + (master_height // 2)) - (my_height // 2)
        geometry = f"{my_width}x{my_height}+{pos_x}+{pos_y}"
        self.geometry(geometry)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    def centerOnScreen(self):
        # self.parent.withdraw()
        # self.parent.update_idletasks()  # Update "requested size" from geometry manager
        
        # Calculate the geometry to center the form
        scrnWt = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth( )
        scrnHt = self.parent.winfo_screenheight( )        
        imgWt = self.winfo_reqwidth()
        imgHt = self.winfo_reqheight()        
        imgXPos = (scrnWt // 2) - (imgWt // 2)
        imgYPos = (scrnHt // 2) - (imgHt // 2)
        self.geometry( '+%d+%d' % (imgXPos, imgYPos) )
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------   
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CLoginForm(CModalForm):
    def __init__(self, winParent, title, centeredOnParent=False, centeredOnScreen=False, modal=False, bkgImg="bkg-3.png"):
        CModalForm.__init__(self, winParent, title, centeredOnParent=centeredOnParent, centeredOnScreen=centeredOnScreen, modal=False, bkgImg="bkg-3.png")        
        self.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', 'SystemButtonFace')
        self.withdraw()
        
        #username label and text entry box
        usernameLabel = Label(self, text="User Name")
        usernameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        username = StringVar()
        usernameEntry = Entry(self, textvariable=username)
        usernameEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)  
        
        #password label and password entry box
        passwordLabel = Label(self,text="Password")
        passwordLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)  
        password = StringVar()
        passwordEntry = Entry(self, textvariable=password, show='*')
        passwordEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)  
        
        validateLogin = partial(self.validateLogin, username, password)
        
        #login button
        loginButton = Button(self, text="Login", command=self.validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=0)  
        
        self.deiconify()
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    def validateLogin(self, username, password):
        print("username entered :", username.get())
        print("password entered :", password.get())
        return
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from tkinter import Tk
    
    mainWin = Tk()
    
    CLoginForm(mainWin, "Login Form")
    
    mainWin.mainloop()
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What does "the login form expands by itself indefinitely" mean exactly?

Comment: It resizes/expands itself forever entering _resize_image(). The problem seems be related to layout management implemented using grid, if I comment out usernameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0) and any other row containing a grid(..) the window does not expand itself.

Comment: TypeError: CLoginForm.validateLogin() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'password'

Comment: btw, add self to `self.username` and `self.password` U need to add lambda on `loginButton`  keyword  `command=lambda: self.validateLogin(self.username.get(), self.password.get()))`

Comment: I got it working by comment out `#self.wm_attributes`